# Splitting up a string

Tags: java, split

I would like to take the code below and take the 5 number string the I input into the box and output 5 spaces in between each number.  So I could enter `12345`, and the output would be `1     2     3     4     5`.

I'm not sure how to do this, or where to insert the code.

```
String number;

while (true)
{
number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Number");       

if(number.length() >5 )
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter a 5 digit number!","Try again",
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
else break;
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The new result is " + number,"Results",
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        System.exit(0);
```

Thanks

Comment: I recognize this code sample as being part of your homework assignment.  Note that the title of the homework assignment is "Practice Arithmetic Operators", so you might want to look at using arithmetic operators instead of regexp or string manipulation.  Hint: the Java operators for division (/) and remainder (%) make this pretty easy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

regexes are so fun, this code just adds a space after each number :

```
String numbers = "12345";
numbers = numbers.replaceAll("(\\d)", "$1 ").trim();
```

Comment: It's working, but how do I make it 5 spaces?  Right now it does one space.

Comment: replaceAll() function works as there was a global flag, it adds a space after each number.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you want a non-regex solution

```
    String result = "";
    for(char c : number.toCharArray())
    {
        result = result + c + " ";
    }
    result = result.trim();
```

Comment: I am from the StringBuilder police and you are in jail:) Just kidding:)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("12345".replaceAll("(.(?!$))", "$1 "));
```

This appends a space to any character that isn't at the end of the string (which means you don't need to call `.trim()`). If you want more spaces add them at the `"$1 "` part.